# Support Multiple Screens from Expansion File

Tags: android, android-drawable, apk-expansion-files

I organized my drawables in different drawable/ folders to support tablets and phones from mdpi up to xxxhdpi. As the apk-file gets big because of the high density drawables (most of my drawable folders are larger than 50MB) I have to use expansion files.

Question:
As of now Android devices pick the drawables they need from one of the drawable/ folders automatically. This works well and I don't want to loose this feature. But if I put my drawables into an expansion file I will loose this feature. 
What is best practice in this case?

One solution could be to read the devices metrics and load the resources from the expansion pack. But again, I don't want to pick the images myself as android does this very well.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Play allows you to publish multiple APKs under the same application listing. Google Play then supplies each APK to the appropriate devices based on configuration support you've declared in the manifest file of each APK.

check http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html for more details

Comment: Hi Aun, thanks for the idea. Unfortunately most of my drawable folders are larger than 50 MB so it won't work for me. I'm searching for a way to handle drawables for different screen sizes from an expansion pack easily.